# Is there a way to have "extends T" be used as a return type?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to define an interface, where an object's type can be a class *or* anything that extends that class. Similar to how in GraphQL APIs, anything that `implements` an interface can be a valid return object.

I was hoping for something like:

```
interface Person {
  name: string
}

interface Superman extends Person {
  clothes: string
}

interface Home {
  address: string
  owner: Person | T extends Person
}
```

Essentially, any object that implements `Person` or `Superman` can be an acceptable type for `owner` field.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: ...`owner: Person`?

Comment: Anthing that extends `Person` is also assignable to `Person`. Do you want to make `Home` generic, so that you can access fields of the `Person` subtype? Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wg8byN)? If that's not what you want, please [edit] your question to add more details about your goal here.

Comment: Thanks Alex! Ah yeah, that's what I was going for. Sorry for not making a clear question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a generic type like this:

```
interface Home<T extends Person> {
  address: string
  owner: T
}
```

This lets you accept a type that extends `Person` as a parameter to the `Home` type, and use that somewhere in your type.

Now you can use `Superman` as `T` and then access fields that are not declared on `Person`.

```
const superman: Superman = {
  name: 'Clark',
  clothes: 'cape',
}

const home: Home<Superman> = {
  address: '123 Fake St',
  owner: superman
}

console.log(home.owner.clothes) // fine
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmBAvgQaJLIigMoCuAB2hk4uCAA9IIACYY0mHPiLIEAGyxgAFhAzVa9EE1btw0eEmQAJLBQA8AFWQSps+VGwgAfEuJxp0qB1dGjpGZSwAdxBoansWNgQcWhpBYVFqfiEoEVwAXh8ScipkAHIAYVU4KABrEoAaZTUNbWCShDgheviCRJBkzRti6ztMtK9kfMJff0CMVoBGACYAZmQAMThq3jAu4kjoqD1U7NEG417sVQgAOnUGAAoBimv96GumrR0ASmQAel-kDBQBACEA)